# Can't connect AdonisJS to SQL Server database

Tags: node.js, adonis.js, sql-server-2014-express

I use AdonisJS and SQL Server. I'm trying to connect my application to SQL Server, but it's not working.  It works if I connect with SQL Server Management Studio:

[image]

But when I try to make a migration, I get an error.  Here is my config/database.js: https://hasteb.in/odixoxom.kotlin

My `.env` :

```
DB_CONNECTION=mssql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=1433
DB_USER=sa
DB_SERVER=DIDI-PC
DB_PASSWORD=123456
DB_DATABASE=WEB_PANEL
```

Does someone have a solution?  Thanks!

Comment: You should **NOT** use the `sa` account ! Create your own personal account, or an application-specific account, and use those - not the "almighty" `sa` acount!!

Answer (score 0):

I have the answer :)

it doesn't work like with mysql, there I have to create the db first and then access it, with mysql it was adonisjs who did it it it seems to me :)

And the "sa" username is just for testing haha, don't worries

Thanks !!